# Requests module for python not being recognized

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am on a Mac.
I installed the requests module to do some web scraping but whenever I run the file it is telling me that it doesn't recognize the requests module. I then checked if the module is installed and it was. I've attached a screenshot.

And here is the error message

```
  File "scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

[image]

Comment: Add the error message too

Comment: how are you running your program? is the python binary you are using to execute the program the same that has requests installed or are you using another virtual environment?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am not sure how to check for that. But I don't have a separate environment.

Comment: open a console. type `python` then once inside the python interpreter type `import requests`. If no error message appears type `exit()` to return to the console. Now type `python scraper.py` to execute your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it seems like it is working now. See the answer below in case it benefits others.

Comment: @OmidShojaee could you remove the downvote please now that my question is clear?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the different versions of Python I have. Mac ships with 2.7 by defualt and even though I installed the requests module it was installed for the default python version.
So what I did was

1. Installed the latest Python version
2. Changed the default Interpreter Path in Vscode . Here is the official Vscode guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
3. And finally installed requests for Python 3 using this command in the terminal

```
sudo python3 -m pip install requests
```

You may need to update your pip too

`pip install --upgrade pip`

I still think I need to manage the Python environments better but that is for another time.